# Cant retrieve (hidden?) properties from Web HTML when parsing with VBA Excel

Tags: html, excel, vba, parsing, web-scraping

I want to retrieve a short string data from a web page that though visible it cant be selected nor copied with cursor. When inspecting the code i find that the desired info is under the "value" Property of the id element copied below "txtMaturity". But when trying to get the "attribute" with VBA in Excel it comes out empty ("").

As a check, with the same procedure but just calling for "innertext" (or several other i tried) on other parts of the page the result is ok as expected ("txtMaturity") so believe not a problem of VBA code.

Is there another way of calling info inside Properties of the code? Evidently there is a restriction or hidden property that limits interaction in the live page. Given i see the info in the code there should by some call to it.

HTML structure:

```
<html  xmlns= ”http://www.w3.org/1999/html” class>
 <body data-spy=”scroll” data-target=”#nav-wrapper”>
  <div class=”foo” >
   <div class=”foo2”>

    <input id="txtMaturity" class="form-control input-sm" type="text" readonly="true"> 

   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

VBA procedure (pls dont mind if nesting is redundant, just a proxy of real code)

```
Sub getWeb()

Dim xhr As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim doc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim table As HTMLHtmlElement

Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP") 

    With xhr
        .Open "GET", url
        .send

        While .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
            doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set table = doc.getElementsByClassName("foo")(0).children(0)

     output = table.getElementsByClassName("form-control input-sm")(0).getAttribute("value")

End sub
```

output: ""

Web: http://www.mae.com.ar/legales/emisiones/ONDetalle.aspx?id=1415

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the desired output? "True"?

Comment: Can you supply the URL and the expected outcome?

Comment: @qharr Target web page. Desired output are the text enclosed in any of the textboxes: “03/05/2018”/“normal”/name. Any of them will suffice. Should be able to replicate for the rest. As an example, the “Fecha/Date” header (in bold) is easily retrieved (id: txtFecha) but not the data/value (“03/05/2018”). http://www.mae.com.ar/legales/emisiones/ONDetalle.aspx?id=1415

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key is to have the page fully loaded before trying to extract info as those values are populated by a javascript function when page is loaded I believe. Your current method is trying to pull values which haven't been populated yet.

---

### With Selenium:

This should work using [selenium basic](http://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/).  The danger with the below is if the page load exceeds the default selenium timeout wait for the page.

```
Public Sub test()

    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver

    With d
         .Start "Chrome"
         .Get "http://www.mae.com.ar/legales/emisiones/ONDetalle.aspx?id=1415"

         Debug.Print "Nombre: " & .FindElementById("txtNombre").Value
         Debug.Print "Emisores: " & .FindElementById("txtEmisores").Value
         Debug.Print "Descripcion: " & .FindElementById("txtDescripcion").Value
         Debug.Print "MonedaEmision: " & .FindElementById("txtMonedaEmision").Value
         Debug.Print "Fecha: " & .FindElementById("txtFecha").Value
         Debug.Print "Vencimiento: " & .FindElementById("txtVencimiento").Value
         Debug.Print "Estado: " & .FindElementById("txtEstado").Value

         Stop

         'Other stuff
        '.Quit
   End With

End Sub
```

---

### With IE

This method is a little more reliable, perhaps, as a loop is introduced to "wait" for one of the target values to be populated. You will want to add an explicit timeout in there to mitigate for a never-ending loop. That said, there are some additional selenium wait methods beyond the default timeout for page load and you can loop until items become available as with the below.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim html As HTMLDocument

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://www.mae.com.ar/legales/emisiones/ONDetalle.aspx?id=1415"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        '<== Probably want to add a timeout for next loop
        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop While .document.getElementById("txtNombre").Value = vbNullString

        Set html = .document

        With html
            Debug.Print "Nombre: " & .getElementById("txtNombre").Value
            Debug.Print "Emisores: " & .getElementById("txtEmisores").Value
            Debug.Print "Descripcion: " & .getElementById("txtDescripcion").Value
            Debug.Print "MonedaEmision: " & .getElementById("txtMonedaEmision").Value
            Debug.Print "Fecha: " & .getElementById("txtFecha").Value
            Debug.Print "Vencimiento: " & .getElementById("txtVencimiento").Value
            Debug.Print "Estado: " & .getElementById("txtEstado").Value
        End With

        Stop
        'Quit '<== Remember to quit application
    End With

End Sub
```

---

**Output:**

[image: Output]

---

**References:**

1. Microsoft Internet Controls
2. HTML Object Library

Comment: Awesome. Thanks.